# What is the best AA NiMH battery charger?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, battery, charger

Let's settle this once and for all...

What are the best AA NiMH chargers out there for:

1. prolonging the life of the batteries
2. charging quickly
3. nothing else

Comment: Why "nothing else"?

Comment: Not really sure what this is asking. It comes across fairly argumentative...and the basis for the question is completely lacking. It doesn't really seem to have anything specifically to do with photography either. I'm fixing to close...but I'll give the author a chance to rework their question if they are looking for something specifically related to a camera equipment issue they are having before I do.

Comment: -1 from me. I'm inclined let it be closed (and put my vote in as such) mostly for it being off-topic, but the argumentative tone didn't help... OP gets less 'noob lenience' with me as a user with prior SE experience who should be more familiar with the 'SE Way' of doing things. I think the question could possibly be saved, but the OP would have to put some effort into reworking it...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that this belongs on the photography site, but personally I'm a fan of the [La Crosse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00077AA5Q) charger (BC-9009 or BC-700).  It charges each individual battery, offers a basic recharge, a discharge for prolonging the life, and a refresh for restoring old batteries or getting new ones up to their peak (it runs it through multiple discharge/recharge cycles).  If you have a bad battery, it will tell you which one.  It also lets you adjust the current to charge faster, but I personally charge everything at the slowest rate (there's a lot of debate on what's best).

Only downside I've experienced is that a completely dead battery takes a bit of work to get it to charge (the charger doesn't detect it).  The trick is to unplug it and short the positive terminal with a neighboring battery for 30 seconds using a paper clip, which will give it just enough charge to be detected.